# If $A$ is a $2 \times 2$ real matrix, then what is $\mathbb{R}[A]$ isomorphic to?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, ring-theory

If $A$ is a $2 \times 2$ real matrix, then what is $\mathbb{R}[A]$ isomorphic to as a ring?

I have proven that $\mathbb{R}[A] \simeq  \frac{\mathbb{R}[x]}{\langle p(x)\rangle}$ where $p(x)$ is the minimal polynomial of $A$.

Then if $p(x)=x+a$, we have $\mathbb{R}[A] \simeq \mathbb{R}$.

If $p(x)=x^2$ such that $A$ is a nilpotent, then $\mathbb{R}[A] \simeq \frac{\mathbb{R}[x]}{\langle x^2\rangle}$

What if $p(x)=x^2+ax+b$?

Comment: It almost feels like you're too focused on the problem you're trying to solve, and you've forgotten that you can solve problems of the form "describe the quotient of a polynomial ring over a field by a polynomial".

Comment: @AdamHughes Good point I totally ommited. Thanks, deleting.

Comment: @DonAntonio cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p(x) = q_1(x)^{e_1}\ldots q_r(x)^{e_r}$ be a product of powers of distinct, irreducible factors of $p(x)$. Then by the Chinese remainder theorem,

$$\Bbb R[x]/(p(x))\cong \bigoplus_{i=1}^r \Bbb R[x]/(q_i(x)^{e_i})$$

In your specific case, if $x^2+ax+b=q_1(x)q_2(x)$ is a product of distinct irreducibles

> $$\Bbb R[A]\cong \Bbb R\oplus \Bbb R$$

as a **ring**. That is to say the multiplication is that of the direct sum, i.e. $(a,b)\cdot (c,d)=(ac,bd)$.

If $p(x)$ is irreducible, then the roots are complex and

> $$\Bbb R[A]\cong \Bbb C.$$

Finally if $p(x) = q(x)^2=(x-a)^2$ then

> $$\Bbb R[A]\cong \Bbb R\oplus\Bbb R$$

as a **set** with the ring multiplication given by $(a,b)\cdot(c,d)= (ac, bc+ad)$.

Comment: I know that Chinese Remainder Theorem works when $<q_1(x)>$ and $<q_2(x)>$ are coprime (i.e. $<q_1(x)>+<q_2(x)>=R[x]$. If $<q_1(x)>=<x-3>$ and $<q_2(x)>=<x-6>$, how to get $1\in R[x]$ from their sum?

Comment: @Kenneth.K consider $1={1\over 3}\bigg((x-3)-(x-6)\bigg)\in \langle x-3\rangle+\langle x-6\rangle$. Remember ideal sums mean sums of everything in the ideals, in particular scalar multiples of the generators.